# Can I read the hash portion of the URL on my server-side application (PHP, Ruby, Python, etc.)?

Tags: http, language-agnostic, uri-fragment

Assuming a URL of:

```
www.example.com/?val=1#part2
```

PHP can read the request variables `val1` using the GET array.

Is the hash value `part2` also readable? Or is this only upto the browser and JavaScript?

Answer (score 215, accepted):

The main problem is that the browser won't even send a request with a fragment part. The fragment part is resolved right there in the browser. So it's reachable through JavaScript.

Anyway, you could parse a URL into bits, including the fragment part, using [parse_url()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php), but it's obviously not your case.

Answer (score 100):

Simple test, accessing http://localhost:8000/hello?foo=bar#this-is-not-sent-to-server

```
python -c "import SimpleHTTPServer;SimpleHTTPServer.test()"
Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 8000 ...
localhost - - [02/Jun/2009 12:48:47] code 404, message File not found
localhost - - [02/Jun/2009 12:48:47] "GET /hello?foo=bar HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

The server receives the request without the #appendage - anything after the hash tag is simply an anchor lookup on the client.

You can find the anchor name used within the URL via javascript using, as an example:

```
<script>alert(window.location.hash);</script>
```

The parse_url() function in PHP can work if you already have the needed URL string including the fragment (http://codepad.org/BDqjtXix):

```
<?
echo parse_url("http://foo?bar#fizzbuzz",PHP_URL_FRAGMENT);
?>

Output: fizzbuzz
```

But I don't think PHP receives the fragment information because it's client-only.

Answer (score 48):

It is retrievable from Javascript - as `window.location.hash`. From there you could send it to the server with Ajax for example, or encode it and put it into URLs which can then be passed through to the server-side.

Comment: Thanks! So to be clear, instead of this: `www.example.com/?val=1#part2`

You'd have to redirect to it on the server, like this:

`www.example.com/?redirectUrl=%2F%3Fval%3D1%23part2`

and of course you'd have to add in support to redirect to that other url in your other page. Not awesome, and doesnt work for all use cases of course, but does work for bookmarks. Note that if you do this, you shouldnt allow redirects to absolute urls, only relative urls, to ensure you don't open yourself up to [unsafe redirects](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Unvalidated_Redirects_and_Forwards_Cheat_Sheet)

Answer (score 26):

The hash is never sent to the server, so no.

Answer (score 9):

The answer is no.

The main purpose of the hash is to scroll to a certain part of the page where you have defined a bookmark. e.g. Scroll to this Part when page loads.

The browse will scroll such that this line is the first visible content in the page, depending on how much content follows below the line.

Yes javascript can acces it, and then a simple ajax call will do the magic

Answer (score 5):

What about:

**Dynamically grab the #hash**

```php
<script>
var urlhash = window.location.hash, //get the hash from url
    txthash = urlhash.replace("#", ""); //remove the #
    //alert(txthash);
</script>

<?php
$hash = "<script>document.writeln(txthash);</script>";
echo $hash;
?>
```

To make it more fluent:

**Full Example using just Javascript and PHP**

```php
<script>
var urlhash = window.location.hash,  //get the hash from url
txthash = urlhash.replace("#", "");  //remove the #

function changehash(a,b){
   window.location.hash = b; //add hash to url
   //alert(b); //alert to test
   location.reload(); //reload page to show the current hash
}
</script>

<?php $hash = "<script>document.writeln(txthash);</script>";?>

<a onclick="changehash(this,'#hash1')" style="text-decoration: underline;cursor: pointer;" >Change to #hash1</a><br/>
<a onclick="changehash(this,'#hash2')" style="text-decoration: underline;cursor: pointer;">Change to #hash2</a><br/> 

<?php echo "This is the current hash: " . $hash; ?>
```

Comment: PHP still doesn't get the hash value.

Comment: sweet and short solution.

Answer (score 3):

I think the hash-value is only used client-side, so you can't get it with php.

you could redirect it with javascript to php though.

Answer (score 2):

Th part of an [URI](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986) after the `#` is called "fragment" and is by definition only available/processed on client side (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier).

On the client side, this can be accessed using javaScript with `window.location.hash`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$url=parse_url("http://domain.com/site/gallery/1?user=12#photo45 ");
echo $url["fragment"]; //This variable contains the fragment
?>
```

This is should work

Comment: IF you have the url as string is easy, even if you parse it with reg exp. The problem is that you can't access #photo45 from the server (use phpinfo() and you won't see #photo45 anywhere

Comment: That does not do anything on the initial request for that page

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can:

Use this method to prevent errors:

```
<script> 
query=location.hash;
document.cookie= 'anchor'+query;
</script>
```

And of course in PHP, explode that puppy and get one of the values

```
$split = explode('/', $_COOKIE['anchor']);
print_r($split[1]); //to test it, use print_r. this line will print the value after the anchortag
```

Comment: That does not do anything on the initial request for that page

Answer (score 0):

We can do it with another approach too, Like first of all get the hash value from js and call the ajax using that parameter and can do whatever we want

Answer (score 0):

Here is more complete code that you can start with:

```
<script>
    sendTokenParameter();

    function sendTokenParameter() {
        if (!window.location.hash) {
            return;
        }

        const id_token = window.location.hash.split('&').filter(function(el) { if(el.match('id_token') !== null) return true; })[0].split('=')[1];
        if (!id_token) {
            console.error('No token returned');
            return;
        }

        window.location.href = `${window.location.pathname}?id_token=${id_token}`
    }
</script>

<?php

process_login();
function process_login() {
    $id_token = $_GET['id_token'];
    if (!$id_token) {
        // Let the javascript code to send the token
        return;
    }
    
    // Do stuff with the token
    
}

?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Another solution is to add a hidden input field to the php page:

```
<input type="hidden" id="myHiddenLocationHash" name="myHiddenLocationHash" value="">
```

Using javascript/jQuery you can set the value of this field on the page load or responding to an event :

```
$('#myHiddenLocationHash').val(document.location.hash.replace('#',''));
```

In php on the server side you can read this value using the $_POST collection:

```
$server_location_hash = $_POST['myHiddenLocationHash'];
```

Comment: That does not do anything on the initial request for that page

Comment: I agree, it works for the subsequent requests, not for the first load.