# Get entire URL, including query string and anchor

Tags: php

Is there a way to get the entire URL used to request the current page, including the anchor (the text after the `#` - I may be using the wrong word), in included pages?

i.e. page foo.php is included in bar.php. If I use your solution in foo.php, I need it to say `bar.php?blarg=a#example`.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/940905/can-php-read-the-hash-portion-of-the-url/940918

Answer (score 91, accepted):

No, I am afraid not, since the hash (the string *including* the #) never gets passed to the server, it is solely a behavioural property of the browser.  The `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` variable will contain the rest however.

If you really need to know what the hash is, you will have to use the `document.location.hash` JavaScript property, which contains the contents of the hash (you could then insert it in a form, or send it to the server with an ajax request).

Answer (score 16):

```
// find out the domain:
$domain = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
// find out the path to the current file:
$path = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];
// find out the QueryString:
$queryString = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
// put it all together:
$url = "http://" . $domain . $path . "?" . $queryString;
echo $url;

// An alternative way is to use REQUEST_URI instead of both
// SCRIPT_NAME and QUERY_STRING, if you don't need them seperate:
$url = "http://" . $domain . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
echo $url;
```

Answer (score 5):

You can't - you'll have to write the value of the hash to a cookie via Javascript to send it to the server on the subsequent request.

Comment: Can you elaborate on that or provide some reference information on doing that?

Answer (score 5):

You can pass up the full URL, including the anchor (the part after the #), using a Javascript onload function that sends that URL to an Ajax endpoint.

Answer (score 2):

This example show's full URL request with `port` or `https`

```
function curPageURL() {
            $pageURL = 'http';
            if(isset($_SERVER["HTTPS"]))
            if ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") {
                $pageURL .= "s";
            }
            $pageURL .= "://";
            if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80") {
                $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"] . ":" . $_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
            } else {
                $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
            }
            return $pageURL;
        }
```

usage : `echo curPageURL();`

Comment: This doesn't answer the crux of the question. Returning the portion of the url after the #

Answer (score 0):

It is true that you can't pass hash data to server. but sometimes what you want is get some url with '#blablabla' from the server, like when you share link to someone with '#', but the site need to login. below is another way to think, maybe not vary detailed.

First, sometimes you want to share your link with '#',like:

```
www.so.com#lala
```

First, you can change your url use javascript and pass some data with '?' and '#' at the same time, like:

```
www.so.com?foo=lala&&flag=hash#lala
```

then, as the '#' nerver pass to the server, but you can get the data from $_GET[''],like:

```
if($_GET['flag'] === 'hash'){

  // base url
  $_SESSION['url'] = strtok('http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"],"?"); 

  // hash data
  $_SESSION['hash'] = $_GET['foo'];
}
```

then, you can do everything with the '#' data, if you want to pass it to client, you can:

```
$url = $_SESSION['url']."#".$_SESSION['hash'];
header("Location:".$url);
```

At last, the url is back

Comment: This is an interesting concept, but without showing the JavaScript it is of little value.

Answer (score -1):

Syntax Error is right.
And what I'd like to do is intercept the #foo from the call dosomething.org/page.php#foo and act as if I'd found a dosomething.org/page.php?x=foo call.  Yes, this may function on the client but it's theoretically available at the server.

Why do I want this?  Because people have old links stashed in their emails and I want to handle them differently.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -5):

You can pass the anchor using rawurlencode funcion.

Basically you just need to do something like this:

```
bar.php?blarg=a<?php echo rawurlencode('#blahblahblah')?>
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. He wanted to read the named anchor from the url, not encode one for output.