# How to retrieve complete URL from address bar using PHP?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get full URL on the address bar using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4768181/how-to-get-full-url-on-the-address-bar-using-php)

I use this function, but it does not work all the time. Can anyone give a hint?

```
function sofa_get_uri() {
    $host = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
    $self = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
    $query = !empty($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']) ? $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] : null;
    $ref = !empty($query) ? "http://$host$self?$query" : "http://$host$self";
    return $ref;
}
```

I want to retrieve the link in address bar (exactly) to use it to refer user back when he sign out. The urls are different:

```
http://domain.com/sample/address/?arg=bla

http://domain.com/?show=bla&act=bla&view=bla

http://domain.com/nice/permalinks/setup
```

But I can't get a function that works on all cases and give me the true referrer.

Hint please.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

How about this?

```
function getAddress() {
    $protocol = $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on' ? 'https' : 'http';
    return $protocol.'://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
}

echo getAddress();
```

Comment: Conditional statement in `$protocol` should  be `isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) === true`.

Comment: be aware: this is quick and dirty solution, but works most of time. this approach contains couple of things worth of being considered. HTTPS and HTTP_HOST aren't standard and could be omitted or wrongly configured. HTTP_HOST could be empty or contain any string data (+ could be "client-hacked" using Host in request header). best practice is to use multiple checks (SERVER_PROTOCOL and REQUEST_SCHEME along with HTTPS; SERVER_NAME is more reliable than HTTP_HOST but also could be wrongly configured). Bottom of line, this function works most of time but it's not universal and reliable solution.

Comment: In case of AJAX request the REQUEST_URI can be different from the REQUEST_URI in address bar.

Answer (score -2):

You could use functions above to retrieve URL till GET parameters.
So You have string like = 'localhost/site/tmp' (example).
After that you could just loop through GET parameters if can't get anything else to work.
Add '?' at the end of string manually.

```
$str = 'localhost/site/tmp/?'
foreach ($_GET as $key => $value) {
    $str .= $key.'='.$value.'&';
}
substr_replace($str, "", -1);
```

echo $str;
At the end You are deleting last symbol which is '&' and is not needed.

Comment: Is this code working correctly?

Comment: Ouput od your code i s localhost/site/tmp/?

Comment: I suppose, it must work correctly, although I haven't tried it yet. Output will be: localhost/site/tmp/?get1=val1&get2=val2. $str must be get from one of the main function with $_SERVER. And all GET parameters will be added.