# How do I parse URL GET data having the URL stored in a variable?

Tags: php

I have an url stored in a variable such as:

```
$url = 'example.com?a=20&i=10'
```

How do I get values stored in variable `a` and variable `i`? Is there a short way to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how do i parse url php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5624370/how-do-i-parse-url-php)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11245963/how-to-retrieve-complete-url-from-address-bar-using-php/11246089#comment14778209_11246089

Check my answer (second answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) and [parse_str](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php):

```
<?php
  $url = 'example.com?a=20&i=10';
  $tmp=parse_url($url);
  parse_str($tmp['query'],$out);
  print_r($out);
?>
```

[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/s9BSXu)

Comment: that gets me the query as a whole. I want to be able to get variables `a` and `i`

Comment: @Liso22 Just use `$out['a']` and `$out['i']`

Comment: @Liso22 if you replace `parse_str($tmp['query'],$out);` with `parse_str($tmp['query']);` you can use `$a` and `$i` directly.

Answer (score 2):

You can use parse_url().

```
data = parse_url($url)
print_r($data['query'])
```

For more details, refer [php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php).

Comment: that gets me the query as a whole. I want to be able to get variables `a` and `i`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
  $url = 'example.com?a=20&i=10';
  $result = parse_url($url);
  parse_str($result['query'],$getVar);
  echo 'value of a='. $getVar['a'];
  echo 'value of i='. $getVar['i'];
```

Comment: Have a look at: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27534/see-who-is-upvoting-downvoting-my-question-answer

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access those variables, check out the extract() function, it will create variables $a and $i from the parse_str() function above.

However, it will overwrite any existing variable called $a so its to be used with caution.

```
<?php
  $url = 'example.com?a=20&i=10';
  $tmp=parse_url($url);
  parse_str($tmp['query'],$out);
  extract($out);
?>
```