# Can I get the value from URL without requesting it ?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I parse URL GET data having the URL stored in a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11408716/how-do-i-parse-url-get-data-having-the-url-stored-in-a-variable)

Can I get the value from URL without requesting the page ( refresh ) or pressing on a link 
I need the value of `p` from this url

```
http://palestinianz.com/?page=person&p=Betty-Shamieh-
```

to use it in the og:title meta tag of Facebook

Comment: $_GET['p'] will contain the value of p.

Comment: You mean you want to parse the URL for the value of `p`?

Comment: @Hamish yes I need the value of p but without requesting the page

Answer (score 0):

```
$url = parse_url("http://palestinianz.com/?page=person&p=Betty-Shamieh-");
parse_str($url['query'], $data);
$p = $data['p'];
```