# Hide one DIV if url variable present and show another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'd like to hide the `<div id="sociallocker">` if the word: email appears in the URL. And show the `<div id="emaillocker"> if it does appear.`

I've tried the following but no luck:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        if (window.location.href.indexOf("email") != -1) {
            $("#sociallocker").hide();
        }
    });
</script>
```

HTML

```
<div id="sociallocker">
    [sociallocker id="1505"] [/sociallocker]
</div>

<div id="emaillocker">[emaillocker] [/emaillocker]
</div>
```

I am running Wordpress with JQuery & Bootstrap on the Genesis Framework. Not sure if I need to add anything else to the JQuery to get it to fire?

Live test: https://www.moneynest.co.uk/test-page-for-stack/

Sam

Answer (score 0):

```
if(document.location.href.indexOf("email") >= 0) {
// do your thing
}
```

Comment: No luck, both continue to display see: https://www.moneynest.co.uk/test-page-for-stack/

Comment: Have you tried using .css(‘display’, ‘none’) instead of .hide()?

Comment: Changed to: <script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
if(document.location.href.indexOf("email") >= 0) {
$("#sociallocker").css(‘display’, ‘none’);
}
});
</script>

but still no luck. Can't help but feel I'm missing something obvious. How can I check if the script is actually firing?

Comment: I used alert(‘fired’) inside my answer and it fires when the address contains the word “email”. So the code works. I am not housing my answer inside $(function () so try removing that.

Comment: Hmmm, still no luck. I think Wordpress might be blocking it from loading?

Comment: You may need to change the PHP in a Wordpress file to retrieve the address then. https://stackoverflow.com/a/11246141/1639594

Answer (score 0):

I think this should solve your problem

```
if (window.location.href.indexOf("email") != -1) {
    $("#sociallocker").hide();
    $("#emaillocker").show();
} else {
    $("#sociallocker").show();
    $("#emaillocker").hide();
}
```