# Get full url with anchor

Tags: php

I have a page with this url (www.mysite.com/index.php?op=2&id=3#someancor).
I would like to use php function parse_url for split the url but I don't know how to take the full url with ancor.
I have tried so:

```
$base_url = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

$parsed_url = parse_url($base_url);
echo $parsed_url['path'];
echo $parsed_url['query'];
echo $parsed_url['fragment'];
```

But my base_url return www.mysite.com/index.php?op=2&id=3.
How can I get the full url?
Thanks

Comment: Not possible. The hash is never sent to the server. The browser uses it locally, by scrolling down to the element with that ID.

Answer (score 3):

then you can use "javascript" > **document.URL**. and POST to some page and process there. document.URL returns the complete url with #

Comment: But Can I put this code in my php class?

Comment: you will post/ajax the url variable to some php page, and fetch the value, and then you can pass it to any function or class, depends upon your coding style

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is impossible as the `#...` part of the url will be handled only by the browser and not being used when requesting the server.

Comment: Good question! Didn't know that before

Comment: Hahaha, don't worry man :)

Answer (score 0):

This is impossible, because everything behind the hash isn't handled by the server. Look at this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/967659/1341719

Answer (score -1):

The function will give you the current url, and you can process it.

```
$base_url= curPageURL();
function curPageURL() {
     $pageURL = 'http';
    if ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") {$pageURL .= "s";}
      $pageURL .= "://";
    if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80") {
       $pageURL .=  $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
    } else {
    $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
    }
    return $pageURL;
   }
```

Comment: It won't provide the part of the URL that the question is asking about.