# PHP get URL content

Tags: php, url

I have a URL

```
http://localhost/ifocus/v3/services.php#nav-section2
```

I want to get hashtags from URL, EX : if the URL contains "#" so capture it via PHP

> ## nav-section2

When i do

```
echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

// Output
/ifocus/v3/services.php
```

Comment: @arkascha you can't detect the hash in PHP, it doesn't get detected by the server.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/967649/get-entire-url-including-query-string-and-anchor

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't detect the hash parameter of the URL in PHP, you would need to use JavaScript.

You could make a jquery call to php which passes the hash data (`window.location.hash`) to a PHP script as a URL parameter and return TRUE/FALSE though.

Comment: makes it more easier as i need the hash for the JS accordian itself

Comment: There you go then - just use `window.location.hash` :)

Answer (score 2):

You can not capture this content for that you need js(client side script)