# php print current url using $_GET

Tags: php, url, get

I am working arround get url in php

my url is

```
http://localhost/my__file.php?location=http://www.testsite.com/photo-gifts/custom_photo_necklace_oval_charm#design=68793492
```

when i am printing url using

```
$_GET['location'];
```

it prints only

http://www.testsite.com/photo-gifts/custom_photo_necklace_oval_charm

it not displaying me full url i.e. #design=68793492

Please help me on this

Comment: `#design=68793492` is *not* part of the `location` parameter. If it should, then the URL is invalid. There's not much you can do from the PHP side that consumes the data.

Answer (score 3):

The last part separated by `#` is the fragment, which is never submitted to the server. You should **URL encode** the entire `location` value so special characters are preserved/lose their meaning.

Answer (score 1):

The anchor tag (#example) won't be detected by PHP as it doesn't get passed on to the server...

You will need to use JavaScript `window.location.hash`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16354426/php-get-url-content/16354457?noredirect=1#comment23429695_16354457

Comment: The question doesn't ask for $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']. OP is simply trying to pass a url as a GET parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You've to encode the location parameter.

First use php urlencode function to encode the url. Then pass the encoded value as a get parameter. "#" and "=" character need to encoded. It is always better to encode the whole URL.

For your example, Try

```
http://localhost/my__file.php?location=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fmy__file.php%3Flocation%3Dhttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.testsite.com%2Fphoto-gifts%2Fcustom_photo_necklace_oval_charm%23design%3D68793492
```

Answer (score 1):

replace `#` by `%2C` in you url or use `urlencode`

Answer (score 0):

You can not capture value after # in php
but if you will pass encoded location value with # value you can get this value.