# can we get hash value on serverside php?

Tags: php, codeigniter, hashtag

I have url like this `http://localhost/project/test/value#value2`. when i hit this url i want to fetch #tag value on server.
I tried like this on server side

```
    <?php 
   function test(param){ ?> 
       <script> 
          var className = window.location.hash;  
          alert(className);
       </script> 
   <?php 
    } ?>
```

this alert giving me class name but after page load if i assign this value to php variable its not working. I m using codeigniter so i tried this `current_url()` function and also i tried `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URL']` but its not working in my case

Comment: try defining the value inside `test` to a variable and then returning the variable.

Comment: This question already discussed here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/940905/can-i-read-the-hash-portion-of-the-url-on-my-server-side-application-php-ruby

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that browser did not send #tag during request, so you don't have it at server side in any url get function, only option for you is process that #tag in js side and load necessary html part through ajax

Answer (score 0):

Please refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6768793/get-the-full-url-in-php)

```
$actual_link = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `parse_url` function.

```
$url = 'http://localhost/project/test/value#value2';

$tokens = parse_url($url);

print_r($tokens);

/*will output
Array
(
    [scheme] => http
    [host] => localhost
    [path] => /project/test/value
    [fragment] => value2
)
*/
```

The `fragment` bit is what you are after.

Comment: its not working becoz i m not getting that url . its server side so if i try current_url() function of CI its not giving me that url with hash tag

Comment: what does `current_url()` return?

Comment: try this `print current_url() . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];`

Comment: oh wait, you can't access the anchor (the hash and everything else) from php, it doesn't get passed over, see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/967649/get-entire-url-including-query-string-and-anchor

Answer (score 0):

You can't get hash tag from url in php. Because browser does not send #tag during processing request.