# Laravel get parameter value after # character

Tags: php, laravel

How can I get the value of the parameter after # character? The Get URI of third party API is `http://example.com/product?name=abc#cde`. I am only getting data of name params as `'abc'`. How can I get full value as 'abc#cde' in laravel.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/967649/get-entire-url-including-query-string-and-anchor#967659

Comment: @Coderman it did not solve my problem as I have to get data from third party url.

Comment: you can use `url()->full()` that will return the full url including the `#`. But treating `#` as value of a parameter, that complicates. you can check more url helpers here https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/urls

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get fragment (value after hash '#') from a URL in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2317508/get-fragment-value-after-hash-from-a-url-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you have a URL as a string and would like to extract the bit after `#`. You don't need Laravel for that, you can achieve it with pure PHP as following:

```
$url_string = 'http://example.com/product?name=abc#cde';
$url = parse_url($url_string);
echo $url['fragment']; // 'cde'
```