# PHP Not Reading After?

Tags: php, api-design

Can't find this question so if it's already been asked, I'd really appreciate being redirected!

So I'm creating a RESTful API with PHP but I can't seem to get the parameters from the API call. The API call is `~/database/table?key=value`, where the tilda represents the connection to my server. Below is my code:

```
$method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
$request = explode('/', $_SERVER['PATH_INFO']);
$body = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
```

So here's what I understand about the above code. I put the method into `$method`, which would be GET, PUT, etc. `$request` then creates an array with each thing separated, which to my understanding would look like :
`[database, table?key=value]`, and `$body` would take whatever data I attach to the request, which in my case would be JSON.

The problem that I'm running into is that the second value of the array is only getting `table` and isn't getting anything after the '?' in the API call. Did I miss something? I thought that `explode` only separated by the character that I defined which was '/'.

Thanks!!

Comment: `var_dump($_SERVER[PATH_INFO])` gives what? `PATH_INFO` also should be in quotes.

Comment: It returned ```/database/table``` and sorry I missed that, I do have the ```PATH_INFO``` in quotes, I'll fix that

Comment: So `PATH_INFO` does not contain the query string. Try`$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/967649/get-entire-url-including-query-string-and-anchor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `PATH_INFO` didn't contain the query string, it was instead stored in `QUERY_STRING`. Sorry for the relatively trivial question and thanks to user3783243!