# PHP & Hash / Fragment Portion of URL

Tags: php, url, mod-rewrite, hash, fragment-identifier

I am trying to find a way to save the hash portion of a url and as a PHP variable.  This idea is a bit kooky, but bear with me...

I'd like to extract the "location" fragment from the following URL and save it as a PHP variable.

```
http://www.example.com/#location
```

However, discussion at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/940905/can-php-read-the-hash-portion-of-the-url) indicates that the fragment of a URL is only reachable through JavaScript.

But would it be possible to create a link where the fragment is duplicated in the URL, parsed by PHP, and then removed by mod rewrite? So....

Original url:

```
http://www.example.com/location/#location
```

PHP gets location variable thanks to the plain "location" in the URL

Apache then rewrites the link to:

```
http://www.example.com/#location
```

I'm curious to know if there is an elegant way to solve this problem.

Comment: You could change the fragment into a $_GET value?

Comment: Nope, you can't. See my Answer

Comment: Here is a solution using javascript and a hidden input field http://stackoverflow.com/questions/940905/can-i-read-the-hash-portion-of-the-url-on-my-server-side-application-php-ruby/43119226#43119226

Answer (score 9):

You'll need to use Javascript to read this.  There are a few different options - upon page load, you could use an XmlHTTPRequest (AJAX request) to tell the server what the additional URL parameters were.  Alternatley you could check to see if there are additional parameters (also via Javascript), and if you find any, post back to a different URL that has these parameters encoded into the URL itself.

Answer (score 5):

The Fragment is never sent to the server, according to this [thread](http://forum.modrewrite.com/viewtopic.php?t=3912&sid=d12035a4f7e92e55e25d2e72772c8ddf) on the Mod_Rewrite forums. So, this might be impossible unless you use AJAX to change the page after the fact.

Another idea would be to have Javascript turn the hash into a $_GET paramater, and then refresh the page.

Comment: Thanks for the replies!

I know the fragment is never sent to the server.  What I'm proposing is a "pseudo fragment" or "double fragment" like

    http://www.example.com/fragment/#fragment

The first fragment would be interpreted by PHP, and then removed by mod_rewrite, rendering the URL as 

    http://www.example.com/#fragment

Maybe this approach makes no sense; I'm not sure if it does, hence my question...

Comment: If you want to send the person back to example.com/#fragment, you would send them to example.com/fragement and then PHP could forward them to example.com/#fragement.

Comment: Great idea to forward the user from  "example.com/fragment" to "example.com/#fragment". I will use a cookie to save the fragment, then forward the page to itself.  Something like this might work:

Example:

link: http://www.example.com/test.php?fragment=turkey

$fragment = $_GET['fragment'];

if (isset($fragment)) {
setcookie("TestCookie", "TestCookie", time()+3600);
header("Location: http://www.example.com/test.php/#$fragment");
}

// do additional stuff based on cookie

Comment: You would end up with 2 entries in the history stack :( And worse, the first always refers to the second so your back button navigation would be bothersome.

Answer (score 0):

you could send hash fragment via AJAX to PHP script and do an immediate refresh (reload of the page)

Answer (score 0):

Once you have send the values to server via AJAX. You can set the fragment values in SESSION. When you refresh the page, you can get the fragment which was set in session and process then display the corresponding content. Because we can't get get the fragment values through PHP_SELF / QUERY_STRING and etc. We need this to increase the speed of our web page like Gmail.

Answer (score -2):

It's contained in the "fragment" value returned from [PHP's parse_url function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php).

From PHP manual:

```
<?php
$url = 'http://username:password@hostname/path?arg=value#anchor';

print_r(parse_url($url));

echo parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
?>
```

Will return:

```
Array
(
    [scheme] => http
    [host] => hostname
    [user] => username
    [pass] => password
    [path] => /path
    [query] => arg=value
    [fragment] => anchor
)
/path
```

Comment: This is true if the fragment is manually supplied to this function, but the problem in relation to the original question is that the fragment part is not sent to the server.