# Getting Data from Querystring in PHP

Tags: php, request.querystring

I don't know how to get data from the `querystring` in PHP.

I'd like to retrieve the data from the `access_token`.

> `http://www.mygridview.com/sephora/index.php?mod=config#access_token=170791786296375|983b6aefceafdb1cf2d5a122-100001848355029|Hc8qGl6xgpXlmhOWQrLv910on_8&expires_in=0`

How do I do this in PHP?

Comment: The correct answer depends entirely on how you intend to make that URL available to PHP. Please clarify. [Also, this is at least a quadruplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=fragment+url+php), so you should point out which of those approaches you have tried and why it's still not working.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP & Hash / Fragment Portion of URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1162008/php-hash-fragment-portion-of-url)

Comment: Which URL are you trying to parse? The current page's URL, or one you've got from somewhere else?

Comment: I want to get current page's url with anchor.

Comment: Then the answer is, you can't, not just with PHP.

Answer (score 1):

The anchor part of a URL never gets sent to the server, so if you are trying to load this information from the current URL it won't be there.

As far as the server is concerned, the URL which is loaded by the browser is `http://www.mygridview.com/sephora/index.php?mod=config`

It's possible (maybe even likely) that some javascript is using the information in the anchor to restore the state of the page after it was altered using AJAX. In that case, it's the Javascript you'll need to look into to get that anchor information sent to the server

Comment: @Shakti Singh: You cannot `parse_url()` the current page's URL to get the fragment, only a given URL string.

Comment: @BoltClock: I thought that like he is fetching the url from DB or any other resource

Comment: @Shakti the clarification in the comments above shows that he isn't

Comment: @Gareth: Cool dude he posted at later time. No worries

Answer (score 0):

You get url and then apply parse function on url.
eg::

```
$url = 'http://username:password@hostname/path?arg=value#anchor';

print_r(parse_url($url));

Output::
Array
(
    [scheme] => http
    [host] => hostname
    [user] => username
    [pass] => password
    [path] => /path
    [query] => arg=value
    [fragment] => anchor
)
```

this fragment is your requirement. If i'm right then try this n got success. :)
Thanks

for get current URL::

```
function getInstance($uri = 'SERVER')
    {

            if ($uri == 'SERVER')
            {
                if (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && !empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && (strtolower($_SERVER['HTTPS']) != 'off')) {
                    $https = 's://';
                } else {
                    $https = '://';
                }

                if (!empty ($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) && !empty ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) {
                    $theURI = 'http' . $https . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

                    if (strlen($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']) && strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']) === false) {
                        $theURI .= '?'.$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
                    }
                }
                 else
                 {
                    $theURI = 'http' . $https . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];
                    if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']) && !empty($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
                        $theURI .= '?' . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
                    }
                }

                $theURI = urldecode($theURI);
                $theURI = str_replace('"', '&quot;',$theURI);
                $theURI = str_replace('<', '&lt;',$theURI);
                $theURI = str_replace('>', '&gt;',$theURI);
                $theURI = preg_replace('/eval\((.*)\)/', '', $theURI);
                $theURI = preg_replace('/[\\\"\\\'][\\s]*javascript:(.*)[\\\"\\\']/', '""', $theURI);

        }
        echo (string)$theURI;
    }
```

Comment: try this  $_SERVER['PATH_INFO']

if not work then see this link
 http://www.webcheatsheet.com/PHP/get_current_page_url.php

Comment: I have already tried this one. but this is not returning the anchor string.

Comment: @Chirayu No offense but if you had taken the time to use the search function before asking your question, then you'd know that the fragment cannot be retrieved from the Server environment. You have to actively pass it into the script. See the linked question and search results I've put below your question.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout http://www.routesjs.com, you should be able to get the values and send it off with ajax.