# PHP - get everything after the #?

Tags: php

I've got a flash file (that I can't edit) that is making erroneous requests to a file ending in a #. So the link where the file is being accessed is /files/flash/, so the requests are being made for /files/flash/#

Is there any way for me to detect the # in the link so that I can have those pages not load?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/940905/can-php-read-the-hash-portion-of-the-url

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The fragment is not sent to the server, and therefore cannot be accessed via PHP.

In case you are unsure:

```
scheme://host.tld/file/path/filename.ext?uri#fragment
```

The only way to access the fragment is through Javascript or another client-side script.

Comment: beat me to it. deleting mine. upvoting yours.