# SEO - How to avoid search engine crawlers to not read entire URLs

Tags: optimization, url, seo

I have about 7 query-string parameters in my URL :

http://www.examplesitname.com/EN/en/tshirt-jeans.aspx?productid=324175730&documentid=295110&producttitle=Pyjama+Tshirt&categoryid=55479572&source=TreeStructureNavigation&numberpage=1&pos=TG_n_n

If I break it down following are the query string parameters :
productid
documentid
producttitle
categoryid
source
numberpage
pos

Out of these I need to only display **productId** and **documentId** to the search engine, what is the best approach to achieve this?

I could accommodate one more query string parameter named "extendedattributes" which would contain a comma seperated list of remaining parameters which I could separate back in the request and create a response accordingly, but is that a good way to achieve this ? Is there any other better way ?

Thanks

Comment: Why would you want to hide portions od your URL???

Comment: Since these extra parameters do not help in SEO ranking at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing that comes to my mind: # the rest of parameters as follows. And then use JavaScript/Ajax to retrieve rest of the parameter and load content accordingly. However, this method may require design changes as [anything after # does not reach to the web server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/940905/can-php-read-the-hash-portion-of-the-url).

```
http://www.examplesitname.com/EN/en/tshirt-jeans.aspx?productid=324175730&documentid=295110#producttitle=Pyjama+Tshirt&categoryid=55479572&source=TreeStructureNavigation&numberpage=1&pos=TG_n_n
```

Comment: Sounds like a good approach , but I am just inclined towards thinking of response time hit with this approach ?

Comment: almost same. as the page will be loaded only once. subsequent requests are only for data.

Answer (score 2):

Google Webmaster Tools will let you [designate URL-string parameters to ignore or not ignore](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=147959&from=147958&rd=1) when they index your site. (Look under "Site Configuration" and then "Settings.") Doesn't help you with other crawlers, of course, so this is only a partial solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use robots.txt or other techniques to remove all alternatives and add to a sitemap only the urls you need. Search engines will only index those you want.

Comment: We have over a million dynamic URLs not sure if this will work?

Comment: I'm not an expert, but maybe there is a way to use a wildcard value, or a regular expression so you can define any url after your wanted one. I'm sure that this can be automated but I'm not sure that it's the best approach anyway. I just gave my idea, search for more.