# Php to get value of hash from URL

Tags: php, javascript, variables

How can I get a variable of a hash in php.

I have a variable on page like this

```
catalog.php#album=2song=1
```

How can i get the album and song values and put them into PHP variables?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can PHP read the hash portion of the URL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/940905/can-php-read-the-hash-portion-of-the-url)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just adding onto @Alec's answer.

There is a [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/function.parse-url.php) function:

Which can return `fragment - after the hashmark #`. However, in your case it will return *all* values after the hashmark:

```
Array
(
    [path] => catalog.php
    [fragment] => album=2song=1
)
```

As @NullUserException pointed out, unless you have the url beforehand this really is pointless. But, I feel its good to know nonetheless.

Comment: Unless you have the URL beforehand, this is useless.

Comment: Thank you. Sounds like I could work this idea into what I need.

Answer (score 9):

You can't get this value with PHP because PHP processes things server-side, and the hash in the URL is client-side only and never gets sent to the server. JavaScript *can* get the hash though, using `window.location.hash` (and optionally call on a PHP script including this information, or add the data to the DOM).

Answer (score 1):

You can use AJAX/PHP for this. You can get the hash with javaScript and load some contents with PHP.
Let's suppose we're loading the main content of a page, so our URL with hash is "http://www.example.com/#main":

JavaScript in our head:

```
 function getContentByHashName(hash) { // "main"
    // some very simplified AJAX (in this example with jQuery)
    $.ajax({
      url: '/ajax/get_content.php?content='+hash, // "main"
      success: function(content){
        $('div#container').html(content); // will put "Welcome to our Main Page" into the <div> with id="container"
      }
    });
 }

 var hash=parent.location.hash; // #main
 hash=hash.substring(1,hash.length); // take out the #

 getContentByHashName(hash);
```

The PHP could have something like:

```
<?php
// very unsafe and silly code

$content_hash_name = $_GET['content'];

if($content_hash_name == 'main'):
  echo "Welcome to our Main Page";
endif;

?>
```