# $_GET array empty when location hash is in the URL

Tags: php

When I have a URL such as this:

```
http://website.com/?var=foo
```

Then the $_GET array looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [var] => foo
)
```

But when I have a URL such as this:

```
http://website.com/#location?var=foo
```

Then the $_GET array is empty:

```
Array
(
)
```

Is this normal behavior? If so, is there a workaround for this scenario?

Comment: Why isn't the hash at last?

Comment: I would imagine this is normal behaviour, the hash needs to be after the query.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Php to get value of hashtag from URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3847870/php-to-get-value-of-hashtag-from-url)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is correct way of url to get the `$_GET` values

```
http://website.com/?var=foo#location
```

The main problem is that the browser won't even send a request with a fragment part. The fragment part is resolved right there in the browser. So it's reachable through JavaScript.

You could parse a URL into bits, including the fragment part, using **parse_url()**

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/940905/can-php-read-the-hash-portion-of-the-url)

Comment: He is asking how to get values after the hash, not how it should be, He's link is perfectly fine.

Comment: @MihaiIorga: His link isn't perfectly fine, if he wants some GET parameters to appear.

Comment: No, he asked if the behavior is normal, witch is.

Comment: @MihaiIorga i know computers are very literal when interpreting things, but humans shouldn't be.

Comment: @chris I don't think anyone who answered even read the question, all told him that is not a good link but he asked if the behavior is normal and what workarounds he has.

Answer (score 4):

The value after the hash (including the hash) is never sent to the server, so when you do

`http://website.com/#location?var=foo`

the server never sees `#location?var=foo`

Reorder the string so the query string appears before the hash. `?var=foo#location`

Answer (score 1):

Put #location at last so your link became
 http://website.com/?
var=foo#location

Answer (score 1):

This is not the general format of url.

`#location` is a fragment, it should follow the query string

```
http://website.com/?var=foo#location
```