# PHP isset($_GET) not triggered

Tags: php

live at http://vivavidadesign.com/includes/content.php

I have the PHP code:

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET["#photo"])){
    print ("HELLOOOOOOO");    
} else {
    print ("Nothing Set");
}
?>
```

I am using this file in to return files in conjunction with AJAX.

Previously going to http://vivavidadesign.com/includes/content.php#photo would trigger `(isset($_GET["#photo"]))`. I can trigger it with `?photo`, but I want to know how to trigger using a hash i.e. `#photo`

Comment: It won't be triggered since your browser will nor send anchor to your server (and after '#' is an anchor)

Comment: Don't tell me that you are using `id` value, you need to use the `name` *value*, oh I just saw the link, it's just a fragment identifier, you need something like `content.php?get_this=photo`

Comment: I want to trigger an event in PHP using URL hash

Comment: You can't use `$_GET` with `#`. You have to use `?`.

Comment: @MElliott it is working with ? but I wanted to do it using # somehow

Comment: @vivavidadesign : use javascript or get full url and then split it and get hash value to process

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The browser is never sending hash to the server, when requesting data.

You have to send it manually, ie. using jquery:

```
var hash = window.location.hash;
$.ajax({ url: 'content.php?photo=' + hash});
```

Comment: Thank you, I have changed the var url to "/includes/content.php?" + window.location.hash.substring(1); in AJAX in order to send the data, and strip the hash.

Answer (score 1):

PHP does not grab a hash / anchor.
[Can I read the hash portion of the URL on my server-side application (PHP, Ruby, Python, etc.)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/940905/can-php-read-the-hash-portion-of-the-url)

You would have to parse it using Javascript and possibly send via ajax to your php script.

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3847870/php-to-get-value-of-hashtag-from-url).

You do this not with $_GET, but with [parse_url()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php).

The part you are looking for is the `fragment`

```
Array
(
    [path] => includes/content.php
    [fragment] => photo
)
```

Edit to clarify:

If this URL is coming from the client, you're misusing/misunderstanding how the hashtag functions in a URL: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier .  You must parse it client side via javascript.

Answer (score 0):

`#xxx` at the end of URL is not argument to the page but anchor in the page. So PHP doesn't put it in GET variable.

Either use
[code]
 http://vivavidadesign.com/includes/content.php?%23photo
[/code]

if you really need the name of variable to be #photo or you can pass variable in the classic wat like this
[code]
 http://vivavidadesign.com/includes/content.php?photo=something
[/code]

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

if(isset($_GET["photo"])) {
    echo $_GET["photo"];    
} else {
    echo "Nothing Set";
}

?>
```

And call it:

```
 index.php?photo=file.jpg
```

Btw. do not use print if it is not needed, use echo instead.

Answer (score 0):

[How to get the value after the hash in "somepage.php#name"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1917762/how-to-get-the-value-after-the-hash-in-somepage-phpname)

A get is included in the URL after a questionmark, eg.
    `http://www.example.com/?photo=1`
An anchor is included in the URL after a hashtag, eg.
    `http://www.example.com/#photo`
An anchor is never sent to the server from the browser, but you might be able to find it using javascript and through javascript pass it on to the server.

If you want your variable to be a get you need to change the `$_GET['#photo']` into `$_GET['photo']` in your code and `#photo` into `?photo=something` in your URL.

Answer (score 0):

You have to choose one php or javascript to get value :

1. **PHP**

   $ar = explode("#",$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
   print_r($ar[1]);

Demo : https://eval.in/85871

2 **JS:**

```
var hash = window.location.hash;  
document.location.href = '/content.php?photo='+hash;
```