# check url - hash+salt

Tags: php

I have a doubt about how I can check an URL like this:

```
http://your.url/set_new_password.php?userid=564979&code=54c4a2767c2f485185ab72cdcf03ab59
```

I need to check if the userid exists in the database and if the userid is associated to the hash in the link.

I Read that it is not possible check the url within php. If so, is it possible to solve this problem? I need to verify if the hash and userid present in the link exist in the database.

Any other alternatives?

Comment: Hi, why do you want to check the url?? You get the needed values by $_GET['userid'] and $_GET['code']

Comment: $_GET['userid'] and $_GET['code'], who says you can't check the url with php??????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variables `userid` and `code` in the URL are made available to PHP in an array called GET:

```
echo $_GET['userid']; // 564979
```

If you have a hash (or fragment) in your URL, this won't get back to PHP:

```
www.mysite.com?val=1#part2
```

In the above, PHP can see the domain and the `val` variable, but not `#part2`. Sites that use the hash to significantly change the page (eg GMail) use javascript to pull in new content when the hash changes.

Be sure to sanitize your variables **before** using them, to avoid malicious users being able to hack into your system. This is a big topic, but read up on the following:

- [Data Filtering](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.filter.php)
- [PHP Data Objects](http://php.net/pdo)
- [Sanitize and Validate Data with PHP Filters](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/sanitize-and-validate-data-with-php-filters/)

If you don't sanitize, someone could change your url so that the variable is set to:

```
;DELETE * FROM mytable;
```

When you query your db without sanitising your inputs, you could lose all your data.

Comment: but it is so simple, your code checks the URL portion - userid? i read in this link that php can't read the url :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/940905/can-php-read-the-hash-portion-of-the-url              i already read sanitize, what mean that process? thanks

Comment: PHP can't read the #hash part of the URL in the linked question. PHP is server side, the hash can only be seen by the client (browser).

Comment: but to check if the hash exists in the database the php have to read the #hash part of the URL, or i am confusing the problem?

Comment: You're confusing the hash in your case (the value of `code`), with a url hash (which is the part of the url starting with #). You only need the value of `$_GET['code']` - there is no url hash in your url.

Comment: # URL name Attribute not same as a Cryptographic hash

Answer (score 2):

use the $_GET variable in php

```
$_GET['userid']
```

[see tutorial here](http://www.w3schools.com/PHP/php_get.asp)

Answer (score 0):

In PHP, the $_GET array has the url parameters. So in this case, you'd use `$_GET['userid']` and `$_GET['code']`

Answer (score 0):

See Server consist of apache , php , mysql . When you access this url through your browser it is first send to apache which forwards your request to php . Php takes full controle from there on . A request made by client browser consist of various data which can be divided into types cookies , headers , post , get request . All these data can be access in there respective suprglobal variables in php $_GET , $_POST and so on . In your case you need to access $_GET . so do `$_GET['userid']` to access userid , and   `$_GET['code']` to access code . Lastly you would connect ot MYSQL and do querly like "Select * from users where 'userid' = $_GET['userid'] and 'code' = $_GET['code'] " ;