# Facebook Authentication using PHP $_GET Error

Tags: php, facebook, authentication

Failing the facebook PHP OAUTH authentication (the user presses don't allow for example) means facebook adds the correct $_GET endings to the redirect URI i pass it. For example:

www.mysite.com/facebookauth.php?error_reason=user_denied&error=access_denied&error_description=The+user+denied+your+request

No problems there. I can use $_GET to get the error reason and inform the user of what they did wrong.

If it passes however, facebook adds

www.mysite.com/facebookauth.php#auth=WHATEVER

A hash symbol instead of a question mark. And I can't get the authentication code using $_GET. Why? Any Help?

Answer (score 0):

This is why you cannot access the fragment part of an url, it won't be sent to the browser: [Can I read the hash portion of the URL on my server-side application (PHP, Ruby, Python, etc.)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/940905/can-php-read-the-hash-portion-of-the-url)