# using anchors #value in URL, can I call and use this value in php?

Tags: php, url, get, anchor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can PHP read the hash portion of the URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/940905/can-php-read-the-hash-portion-of-the-url)

Hi,
I want to go to a part of my web page where a div called bla bla bla is located.

Using this: http://www.mysite.com/mypage#28 I get there.

But I also need that number to process in php. Does the # work like a ? ($_get) as well?

How do I do that otherwise?

Thanks

Comment: Yes it is. Thanks a lot to point it out. The other thread was very ]

Comment: I should probably have had a better search before I answered this question, but no matter. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with middaparka, Hash values is a client side values can not be loaded from server side, as Facebook Dynamic Url Loading technique

so you can read it is value from a function, and call that function onload of page to do what you need.

Answer (score 0):

In theory you can use the [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) function to obtain this, via the `PHP_URL_FRAGMENT` option. However, in practice I'm pretty sure that there's no guarantee that the browser will pass this information to the server. (i.e.: It won't show up in `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`, so there's no way to pass this information into `parse_url` in the first place.)

As such, you'd need to obtain this client-side via JavaScript and forward it to the server. To do this you can use `window.location.hash`.

e.g.: `<script>alert('The hash value is: '+window.location.hash);</script>`

Answer (score 0):

There is JQuery Plugin "hashchange" using that you can send Ajax request when the hash is changed everytime. You can even bookmark it.
http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-hashchange-plugin/

Check out the demo at http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-hashchange/examples/hashchange/