# CodeIgniter Routing special characters

Tags: codeigniter, routes, special-characters

I'm trying to make CodeIgniter with special character:

```
somepage.com/something#somethingelse
```

Definition in routes.php is:

```
$route['(:any)#(:any)'] = 'eshop/eshop/individual/$1/$2';
```

but it throws me error:

> Message: preg_match(): Unknown modifier '('

Do you have any experience with this? Thank you

Comment: is first (:any) for $1 and second (:any) (after #) for $2 ..?

Comment: Browser will not sent any request after # in url. So, technically this is an invalid routing request. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5971826/2627842) can be a help. You can only achieve this one using javascript.

Comment: Yeah, I'm trying to do it via JavaScript. Anytime, what if I want to use instead of **# ?** ? I'm using CodeIgniter and there is problem, it won't laod string after **?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only:

```
$route['(:any)'] = 'eshop/eshop/individual/$1';
```

After in Javascript:

```
var hash = window.location.hash.substr(1);
```