# Rewrite only valid url using htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

Right now i am using the given below regex

`RewriteRule ^(love-wallpaper.php|quotes-wallpaper.php)+ wallpapers.php`

to rewrite `love-wallpaper.php` and `quotes-wallpaper.php` to `wallpapers.php`

I want above rule should not rewrite wrong url like `love-wallpaper.php&anything`
but should rewrite to url like `love-wallpaper.php?anything` to `wallpapers.php`

How can this be done?

Example :
Urls like `love-wallpaper.php#asdfasdfasdf` should not rewrite to `wallpapers.php`
but url like `love-wallpaper.php?aasdbfsbdf` should redirect to `wallpapers.php`
Thanks

Comment: FYI, your regex would also match `love-wallpaperXphp`, as `.` means 'äny character'. Use `\.` for a regular dot character. Secondly, why are you using `+` which means repeated 1 or more times? Do you want to accept `live-wallpaper.phplove-wallpaper.phplove-wallpaper.php` as an URL?

Comment: Thank you h20,I dnt know much about regex.

Comment: @C1D , edit the question can you now provide any help

Comment: @h2ooooooo No i dnt want to accept that kind of url ,what should i use in place of "+"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably looking for the following:

```
RewriteRule ^(love|quotes)\-wallpaper\.php$ wallpapers.php [QSA]
```

I've also escaped the `-` character, as it's reserved in regex.

Explanation of regex/htaccess:

- `^` - "starts with"
- `(love|quotes)` - the string "love" or the string "quotes"
- `\-wallpaper\.php` - the string "-wallpaper.php" with `-` and `.` escaped.
- `$` - "end must be here"
- `[QSA]` sends your URL parameters (`url.php?my=parameter`) onto the `wallpapers.php` page.

You cannot decide not to match `url.php#hash` as URL hashes cannot be used in .htaccess matching, as they're never sent to the server - see [Redirect URL with hash using .htaccess file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8185188/redirect-url-with-hash-using-htaccess-file)

Answer (score 1):

It's not very clear to me what you are looking for, But If you want to match for a valid query string after `quotes-wallpaper.php` use below rule

```
RewriteRule ^(love-wallpaper.php|quotes-wallpaper.php)+(?![\w&#\$!\(\)]+) wallpapers.php
```

It will not match `&`,`#`,`$` etc after `wallpaper.php`.You can put more symbols in regex character class`[]` if you don't want them to match and rewrite and vice-versa.

Note: This will entirely ignore any query string in passed in url.

Comment: http://www.example.com/celebs-wallpaper.php&ab ,This url is still rewritting to wallpapers.php though its invalid

Comment: @MichelFeldheim yes `(?![\w&#\$!\(\)]+)` is not looking for query string anywhere.It's filtering url that don't have a querystring after `.php` part.If starting charcter is not `?` then it's not a valuid query string and your point is not valid

Comment: I believe `RewriteRule ^(love-wallpaper.php|quotes-wallpaper.php)+(?![\w&#\$!\(\)]+) wallpapers.php` should work as expected.