# Change permalink by htaccess

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I need a help from htaccess expertise

Need to change url to make it user friendly Here is my url of site for example

http://www.example.com/the-collection/#the-colection1/

Here is my wordpress page http://www.example.com/the-collection 
For this page am using 'shortcode' of plugin that automatic add this collection1 with # tag

Here is also pagination come with this plugin then url seems link this

http://www.example.com/the-collection/#the-colection1/page1

What I need I want to make my url like

http://www.example.com/the-collection/page1

I want to remove that #collection1 (only want to remove not replace with any other text because that i can do from backend easily)

Comment: I assume that your plugin is actually reading the hashtag via javascript? is that not the case? if so removing the hashtag will render your script useless

Comment: You can't manipulate hash through htaccess as it is not sent to the server, only on the browser. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/8185251/3305116