# How to use a # in .htaccess (not as comment)

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

Hey this should be a pretty easy question but I can't find the answer to it.

How can I use a # in my `.htaccess`, without turning it into a comment. 
I want to rewrite my url from `www.sitename/index.php#contact` to `www.sitename/index.php`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that all you want to know can be find there:

['hash' url rewrite in .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15133023/hash-url-rewrite-in-htaccess)

[Redirect URL with hash using .htaccess file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8185188/redirect-url-with-hash-using-htaccess-file)

Comment: Thanks this will help. I think I can make it work with this.