# get #var from url in php code error

Tags: php, javascript

i want to get `#var` value from url like my url is `mydomain.com/index.php#1` so i want to get has(#) value from url which is `1` after some research i got this article http://www.stoimen.com/blog/2009/04/15/read-the-anchor-part-of-the-url-with-php/

i use this code for get has(#) value, this is work fine in `JavaScript`  but this is not work in `php` my code is :

```
<script language="javascript">
var query = location.href.split('#');
document.cookies = 'anchor=' + query[1];
alert(query[1]);
</script>
<?php
echo $_COOKIE['anchor'];
?>
```

this code give me `alert` value in `JavaScript` but not `echo` value. any solution for that ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can PHP read the hash portion of the URL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/940905/can-php-read-the-hash-portion-of-the-url)

Comment: @ManseUK: Not a dupe (of that, at least). Did you click on the link supplied?

Comment: @Jon sorry - i clicked the wrong duplicate link .... cannot undo a vote to close !!! Suppose i could delete the comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Additionally, you seem to set wrong property in JS (it's `.cookie`, not `.cookies`):

```
document.cookie = 'anchor' + query[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

The cookie you are setting will not be visible to PHP until the *next* page request. The article you link to *states this explicitly*:

> Of course, yes. This is not working correctly. In fact it’s working
>   correctly from the second load on, but on the initial load of the page
>   the $_COOKIE array does not has any anchor key inside. That’s because
>   this part of the code is executed before the browser setup the cookie
>   on the client.

There is a "workaround" presented in that article, but frankly: this sort of thing is rubbish and you should simply not put this information (only) in the query fragment if you want PHP to read it.

Answer (score 1):

By article which you sent, you must do a redirect like:

```
<?php if (!$_COOKIE['anchor']){ ?>
<script language="javascript">
  var query = location.href.split('#');
  document.cookie = 'anchor=' + query[1];
  window.location.reload();
</script>
<?php } ?>

<?php
echo $_COOKIE['anchor'];
?>
```

Comment: it is not working to `window.location.reload();` my page is continually reloading and nothing is work

Comment: how about making fix from "bjauy" post? i fixed this code. try it now.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting a cookie that wont be passed to php until next reload. Am I wrong?

Client dynamics is the end of the chain.

Answer (score 0):

Use this method to prevent errors:

```
<script> 
query=location.hash;
document.cookie= 'anchor'+query;
</script>
```

And of course in PHP, explode that puppy and get one of the values

```
$split = explode('/', $_COOKIE['anchor']);
print_r($split[1]); //to test it, use print_r. this line will print the value after the anchortag
```