# how to capture the current page url in PHP

Tags: php, url, query-string

I want to get the current page URL with parameters in PHP

the URL is

```
http://localhost/omni/abc.php#def=S6ZT4b9MEsFGDzo
```

I want to get the url part after the `#` sign

Comment: Maybe $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] ?

Comment: Refer to this post: 


  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/940905/can-php-read-the-hash-portion-of-the-url

Comment: Its javascript. I need it in php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Anything after the `#` in a URL is only handled on the client-side. It is not even passed to the request to the server, so there is no way you can directly access it.

Comment: I looked long an hard for this a long time ago and found the same answer. I haven't tried it, but the OP might try an ajax function that calls a php script and deals with it that way, but depending on what the OP actually wants to do, this feels clumsy even as I suggest it.

Comment: Yes. Not only is it clumsy, but it will not be accessible by the page that is being loaded, only by a secondary AJAX request.

Answer (score 0):

Found this little niblet while researching the issue...

http://www.stoimen.com/blog/2009/04/15/read-the-anchor-part-of-the-url-with-php/

```
<script>

var query = location.href.split('#');

document.cookies = 'anchor=' + query[1];

<?php if (!$_COOKIE['anchor']) : ?>

window.location.reload();

<?php endif; ?>

<?php

echo $_COOKIE['anchor'];

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

From this URL: `http://localhost/omni/abc.php?def=S6ZT4b9MEsFGDzo`

`$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` -> `localhost`
`$_SERVER['SCRIPT_URL']` -> `omni/abc.php`
`$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` -> `def=S6ZT4b9MEsFGDzo`

OR

`$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` -> `omni/abc.php?def=S6ZT4b9MEsFGDzo`

OR

`$_SERVER['SCRIPT_URI']` -> `http://localhost/omni/abc.php`