# How to rewrite URL with hash in it?

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can PHP read the hash portion of the URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/940905/can-php-read-the-hash-portion-of-the-url)

I use hash in my url like this,

```
http://mysite.com/home/#/page/manage/
```

I want to get `/page/manage/` via `$_REQUEST` so I try url rewrite mod like this below,

```
RewriteRule ^home/#/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/?$   index.php?url=home&system_url=$1&system_name=$2 [L,QSA]
```

`system_url=$1&system_name=$2` are not sent to `$_REQUEST` of course.

How can I get the result below via `$_REQUEST`?

```
array([url]=>'home',[system_url] => 'page',[system_name] => 'manage')
```

Comment: Everything after the # isn't transmitted to the server. However, you've probably got some AJAX loading going on with a URL structure like that. If you use Firebug or similar you can see the actual URL which is requested, and you can use that to decide what further rewrite rules might be necessary.

Comment: I think you're looking for something like https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history

Answer (score 4):

The fragment part of a URL (the part after #) is not actually sent to the webserver.

Thus, it is not possible to use rewrite to change it