# Access the hash in the current URL with PHP

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can PHP read the hash portion of the URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/940905/can-php-read-the-hash-portion-of-the-url)

Is it possible to access the hash portion of a URL in PHP?

http://test.com/#thisisthehash

In javascript is can be accessed with `window.location.hash`

Comment: Did you see this:: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/940905/can-php-read-the-hash-portion-of-the-url

Answer (score 1):

No this is not possible. Just at client side is that possible.

The HTTP protocol does not transfer this Information, so the server cannot guess it.

Answer (score 0):

No. 
Browser won't send it to the server. 
A dirty workaround would be to send the fragment to the server via an ajax call or by some other way.

Comment: You are right, but that require JavaScript and is asynchron...

Comment: Yeah that's not perfect I agree.