# Using PHP basename to echo ID's to links that have anchor tags?

Tags: php

I was wondering if it was possible in PHP to use the basename function to echo new id's for links (so that I can style them depending on where the user is) if the links are all on the same page? Specifically, my site is a scroll down site, so everything is on one page. I realize you can do the following if my site had multiple pages:

```
<?php $currentPage = basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']); ?>
<ul>
    <li><a href="index.php" <?php if ($currentPage == 'index.php') {
                        echo 'id="here"';} ?>>HOME</a></li>
```

Then of course you'd just style "here" using CSS to reflect the user's current page. But what about if I am using anchor tags?

```
<?php $currentPage = basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']); ?>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.php" <?php if ($currentPage == 'index.php#home') {
                            echo 'id="here"';} ?>>HOME</a></li>
```

This does not work. Is this possible to accomplish using PHP? If not, is there a JavaScript way of doing this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: `php` does not get the current `hash` (it is never send to the server), so reading & acting on `window.location.hash` in javascript seems the way to go.

Comment: This other SO question might be helpful. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/940905/can-php-read-the-hash-portion-of-the-url  There are some JavaScript solutions, which you would need to do in this case due to the server not getting a request when a fragment (ie. #anchorId) is used

Answer (score 0):

The fragment is not sent to the server. All the server knows is that you are on `index.php`.

However, you can use the `:target` psuedo-class to identify which element is referred to in the fragment.

So for instance if I go to `http://example.com/index.php#section` and that page had:

```
<h1 id="section">Some title</h1>
```

And:

```
:target {background-color:#ccc;}
```

Then the `<h1>` tag would be highlighted.