# Is the URL fragment identifier sent to the server?

Tags: http, uri-fragment

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can PHP read the hash portion of the URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/940905/can-php-read-the-hash-portion-of-the-url)

The (famous?) web site mega.co.nz uses a hash mark in URLs to link to encrypted files; the portion of the URL after the hash mark contains a password, and encryption is claimed to happen on the client side. It is certainly feasible to use javascript for client-side encryption but … isn't the URL sent to the server, thus revealing the password to the server itself?

The URL looks like

```
https://example.com/#!encryptedfilename_password
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Fragment identifiers are not sent to the server. The hash fragment is used by the browser to link to elements within the same page.

Comment: Thanks! Yes indeed it is in a sense a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/940905/can-php-read-the-hash-portion-of-the-url , where it is also explained how to use javascript to read fragment identifier