# Can't get very last part of URL

Tags: php, regex, url

So here's what my URL looks like

```
http://localhost/search/s.php?search_query=#hashtag
```

My first response to this was to use `$_GET`

```
$search = htmlspecialchars($_GET['search_query'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
```

So I'd then end up getting nothing, since I had a `#` at the end. So I then tried

```
$url = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
$path = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
$pathFragments = explode('/', $path);
$id = end($pathFragments);
```

I'd echo `$id`, and yet once again get `s.php`
instead.

So my question is, how can I properly do this? I've seen some posts. But none seem to solve my issue.

I'm just trying to get `#hashtag`.

Comment: regex should validate the string as well or not?

Comment: I don't think the hashtag-part is a part of the `REQUEST-URI`

Comment: No need for validation. I just want to get `#hashtag` from the URL. I'd also be having regular words so it has to be dual functioning. @Braj

Comment: @max its not the only way I know to get it to the server is to use javascript and ajax

Comment: Well, `parse_url()` should return a `fragment` index that gives you it, but probably only if the parsed URL contains a fragment (something after a hashtag).

Comment: Already tried that post @JakeGould

Comment: see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14462218/is-the-url-fragment-identifier-sent-to-the-server  and the answer " Fragment identifiers are not sent to the server. The hash fragment is used by the browser to link to elements within the same page.
"  ergo you must use some other method to send it to the server, for example ajax

Comment: If you paste the HTML of the form you are using I can update my answer with the proper jQuery selectors.

Answer (score 0):

You have to send the hashtag to the backend by making an `AJAX`request, preferrably with `jQuery`. Any URL in the `$_SERVER` global variable does not preserve the **fragment identifier** (the part followed by the `#` - pound sign).

```
var hash = window.location.hash;

$.ajax({ ... });
```

Answer (score 0):

with javascript

```
var url = 'http://localhost/search/s.php?search_query=#hashtag';

$(form).submit(function(e){
var url = field.val();
   if(url != '' ){
        var hashtag = url.split('#')[1];
       $.post(serverPageUrl, { "hashtag" : '#'+hashtag }, function(data){
            window.location.href = url; //redirect to simulate original get request.
       });
  }
   return false;
});
```

Comment: so, dynamically send it. even better reason to use javascript

Comment: Not really sure how to _dynamically_ send it over.

Comment: how do they change it? trigger the ajax then

Comment: I'm using a form with `GET`. So they submit it, then I pass it through.

Comment: there updated the answer, you'll probably have to use post though. And here is docs on submit() http://api.jquery.com/submit/, just make sure to return false; like In my example.

Answer (score 0):

Try with Negative Lookahead

```
(?!=#)#\w+$
```

[Online demo](http://regex101.com/r/pU7fA1/3)

Use `(?!=#)#.*$` if there is any thing other then words after `#` till the end of line.

---

Or try using grouping. Get the matched group from index 1.

```
^[^#]*+(.*)$
```

[Online demo](http://regex101.com/r/pU7fA1/4)

Sample code:

```
$re = "/(?!=#)#\\w+$/";
$str = "http://localhost/search/s.php?search_query=#hashtag";

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```

Output:

```
#hashtag
```

Comment: Hash tags are not sent to the server.

Comment: You are looking for regex pattern to get the #hashtag?

Comment: No, just to get whatever is at the end of the url.. And also include the `#`

Comment: so its not the executed result that is given by regex?