# HttpListener not receiving URI fragment

Tags: c#

Im using a web API to recieve an OAuth token which i want to process in my desktop application. The web API redirects the user to localhost:15779 on which i have my application listening using below class.
The problem here is that the API mentioned sends the token via HTTP GET but not using the query parameter (?key=value) but the fragment parameter (#key=value) and i cant change that behaviour because its not my API.
example:

```
http://127.0.0.1:15779/#access_token=b5c283xxxxxxxxe3lili5s003f5fqp&scope=chat_login+user_read
```

If you see the code below you will notice im writing the HttpListenerContext.Request.Url.Fragment into the recievedData variable in order to display it in the browser, for debug porposes. The thing is: its empty.

Any idea on how to get the token?

```
class HttpLstn
{
    public String prefixes;
    public static String recievedData = "";

    private static ManualResetEvent _waitHandle = new ManualResetEvent(false);

    public void start(string prefixes)
    {
        this.prefixes = prefixes;
        if (prefixes == null || prefixes.Length == 0)
            throw new ArgumentException("Wrong listener URL");

        using (HttpListener listenOn = new HttpListener())
        {
            if (!listenOn.Prefixes.Contains(this.prefixes))
                listenOn.Prefixes.Add(this.prefixes);

            listenOn.Start();
            Thread.Sleep(100);
            IAsyncResult result = listenOn.BeginGetContext(new AsyncCallback(ListenerCallback), listenOn);
            _waitHandle.WaitOne();

            Thread.Sleep(100);
            listenOn.Close();
        }
    }

    public static void ListenerCallback(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        try
        { 
            HttpListener listenOn = (HttpListener)result.AsyncState;
            HttpListenerContext context = listenOn.EndGetContext(result);
            HttpListenerRequest request = context.Request;

            //DEBUG
            //write URL Fragment to recievedData in order to display it in the browser for testing purposes
            recievedData = context.Request.Url.Fragment;
            //DEBUG

            HttpListenerResponse response = context.Response;
            string responseString = recievedData;
            byte[] buffer = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(responseString);
            response.ContentLength64 = buffer.Length;
            Stream output = response.OutputStream;
            output.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            output.Close();

            _waitHandle.Set();
        }
        catch (HttpListenerException he) { }
        catch (ObjectDisposedException oe) { }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into this too. Turns out browsers don't send the fragment portion to the server; they keep it and use it to scroll to the indicated portion of the returned document.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14462350/723299