# How to get # part of the Url from HttpContext.Current.Request

Tags: c#, .net, httpcontext

I'm trying to read the # part of an Url using HttpContext.Current.Request in my current application. For example, I've reading a Url https://www.example.com/page1/page2#divId.

The HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.RawUrl returns "https://www.example.com/page1/page2" and excluds "#divId" part of it. I didn't find it in the Request object.

A quick help is required.

Thanks
Chandana

Comment: Is that part even sent to the server?  Check the network debugging tools in your web browser and see if it's even included in the request.

Comment: URL fragments are not sent to the server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The part of the url after the `#` is called *fragment* and is not sent to the server. It's intended to be used client side only.

Check this too: [Is the URL fragment identifier sent to the server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14462218/is-the-url-fragment-identifier-sent-to-the-server)

Answer (score 1):

May be Uri.Fragment Property is help for you.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.fragment.aspx