# Prevent java.net.URL from stripping "?" if there are no query paramters

Tags: java, android, http, url, uri

I am trying to use `java.net.HttpURLConnection` in order to make a request to a URL like this:

```
https://example.com/app/?#/something=else&someting2=else2
```

In order to do this, I need to construct a java.net.url, but the constructor strips away the question mark "?":

```
java.net.URL url = new URL("https://example.com/app/?#/something=else&someting2=else2");
String string = url.toString(); 
// String is https://example.com/app/#/something=else&someting2=else2
```

And when I create the connection with `url.openConnection()`, I just get a 404.

I get why it does this. It righfully recognizes everything after and including the hash # as a url fragment, which means that the actual url becomes `https://example.com/app/?`. And then, it just strips the trailing question mark. But I need the URL to be rendered as is.
This is for an Android app.

How can I force HTTPUrlConnection to make the GET request with the question mark in the URL?

Comment: `%3F` instead of the question mark?

Comment: or rather `%23` instead of `#`?

Comment: @HuguesM. But when I url-encode a URL, I don't encode the #'s, no? How will the server know it has to decode the %23 into a # and then treat it as a fragment marker? Since it was encoded, wouldn't that signal to the server that it should NOT treat it as a fragment marker?

Comment: A fragment identifier is [not sent to the server](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14462350/6730571), so trying to send one does not make sense. So I was assuming it was not really a fragment marker, and that you wanted to send an actual hash sign as part of the URL to the server, in which case you'd need to encode it to `%23`

Comment: Ah, that might the case!

Comment: Posted a proper answer, as I don't like when I see an unanswered question for which I can help, to then discover it was solved in comments :o)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a URL, the part after `?` is a *query string*, and the part after `#` is a *fragment identifier*, as you already noted.

While the query string is sent to the server, the fragment identifier [is not](https://stackoverflow.com/a/940923/6730571), so trying to send one does not make sense.

2 possibilities:

- if it *is* a fragment identifier, you don't need to send it and Android's behavior (normalizing the URL) is correct. Stripping the trailing `?` (empty query string) should not be a problem as it makes no sense alone (for both server and client). If you want to preserve the fragment in your client code, what you want is to create a `URI`, use that to display wherever you want, then convert to `URL` with `toURL()` when you need to speak with server.
- if it is *not* actually a fragment identifier, it's supposed to be part of the query string, so you need to send a hash sign as part of the URL: in that case, you need to url-encode it to `%23`, the part after the `?` won't be stripped, and the server will know what to do with the encoded `%23`.