# How to escape # character in HAProxy config?

Tags: angularjs, haproxy

I'm trying to modularize my front-end which is in Angular-JS, with it we are using HA-proxy as a load balancer and K8s.

Each ACL in the HA-proxy configuration is attached to a different service in K8s and since we are using Angular with the (hash-bang enabled), in the HA-proxy configuration file we use that as a way to identify the different modules.

Below is my configuration, in HA-proxy which is failing because I can't escape the # in the file even after following the [HA Documentation](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.7/configuration.html#2.2).

```
acl login-frontend path_beg /\#/login
use_backend login-frontend if login-frontend

acl elc-frontend path_beg /\#/elc
use_backend elc-frontend if elc-frontend
```

I have tried escaping it as /%23/login and /'#'/admin but without success.

Any idea would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The fragment (everything followed by a `#` character) as defined in [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.5)

> As with any URI, use of a fragment identifier component does not
> imply that a retrieval action will take place.  A URI with a fragment
> identifier may be used to refer to the secondary resource without any
> implication that the primary resource is accessible or will ever be
> accessed.

and it is used on the client side, therefore a client (a browser, a curl, ...) does not send it with a request. As reference: [Is the URL fragment identifier sent to the server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14462218/is-the-url-fragment-identifier-sent-to-the-server)

So there is no point to route/acl with it. The reason why haproxy provide an escape sequence for that is you may want to include it with a body, a custom header... but again, you will not obtain that part from the request line (the first line with URI).

Answer (score 0):

What is really happening here is the user is requesting from HAProxy `/` and Angular, in the user's browser, is then parsing the `#/logic` and `#/elc` part to decide what to do next.

I ran into a similar problem with my [Ember](https://www.emberjs.com/) app. For SEO purposes I split out my "marketing" pages and my "app" pages.

I then mounted my Ember application at `/app` and had HAProxy route requests to the `backend` that serviced my Ember app. A request for "anything else" (i.e. `/contact-us`) was routed to the `backend` that handled marketing pages.

- `/app/* -> server1 (Ember pages)`
- `/      -> server2 (static marketing pages)`

Since I had some urls floating around out there on the web that still pointed to things like `/#/login` but really they should now be `/app/#/login` what I had to do was edit the `index.html` page being served by my marketing backend and add Javascript to that page that parsed the url.  If it detected a `/#/login` it forced a redirect to `/app/#/login` instead.

I hope that helps you figure out how to accomplish the same for your Angular app.