# Django URL does not see the link and its POST request

Tags: python, django, post, django-urls

I made a project, but in it you need to get a special token from the VK social network. I made the token pass along with the link. She looks like this:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/vk/auth#access_token=7138dcd74f5da5e557943b955bbfbd9a62811da7874067e5fa0edef1ca8680216755be16&expires_in=86400&user_id=397697636
```

But the problem is that the django cannot see this link. I tried to look at it in a post request, get request, but everything is empty there. I tried to make it come not as a request but as a link, it is like this:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/vk/auth #access_token=7138dcd74f5da5e557943b955bbfbd9a62811da7874067e5fa0edef1ca8680216755be16&expires_in=86400&user_id=397697636
```

But the django does not want to read the space. Who can help

Comment: some code would help - but surely this is a query parameter, not a hash fragment, and therefore your `#` in the first URL should be a `?`?

Comment: the server sends this fragment: #access_token=7138dcd74f5da5e557943b955bbfbd9a62811da7874067e5fa0edef1ca8680216755be16&expires_in=86400&user_id=397697636
at the end of the link that I indicate: http://127.0.0.1:8000/vk/auth

Comment: If it is, then this is a link to the page where it is described how to get a token: https://vk.com/dev/implicit_flow_user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is a confusion between a query string (get params) that follows a `?` and a fragment (the text, that follows a `#`)

What follows the `#` is not sent to the server (and thus not received by Django) it is only useful to the web browser and to the javascript that is executed on the browser , which can use it to update parts of the screen. use it as virtual urls / bookmarks for one page web applications.
The javascript can of course also trigger AJAX requests using that data, but that's up to the javascript

If you write however `http://127.0.0.1:8000/vk/auth?access_token=7138dcd74f5da5e557943b955bbfbd9a62811da7874067e5fa0edef1ca8680216755be16&expires_in=86400&user_id=397697636` (you replace `#` with `?`)

Then you can receive the information in your django view with

`request.GET["access_token"]`, `request.GET["expires_in"]` and `request.GET["user_id"]`

If it is really a `#`, then your javascript should parse whatever follows the `#` and make the according AJAX requests to the server to send / validate the token.

For another question about  fragments, refer for example to [Is the URL fragment identifier sent to the server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14462218/is-the-url-fragment-identifier-sent-to-the-server)