# Using fragment with route in Symfony

Tags: symfony, routes, fragment, uri

I have a lot of URI like the followings in a legacy dataset:

```
http://data.giving.eu/ontologies/hda/0.1#Domaine/arts-du-langage
http://data.giving.eu/ontologies/hda/0.1#Domaine/arts-du-quotidien
http://data.givings.eu/ontologies/hda/0.1#Tag/police-romaine_police-romaine_police-romaine_Police_romaine
```

I would like to define a route on the basis of
`http://datamusee.givingsense.eu/ontologies/hda/0.1#Domaine/`

and get strings like arts-du-langage, arts-du-quotidien or police-romaine_police-romaine_police-romaine_Police_romaine as parameter of the route. But, I'm not able to find how to do it (i'm using symfony 4.3.3)

My first attempt was

```
/**
     * @Route("/ontologies/hda/0.1#Domaine/{id}")
     */
```

It doesn't work. Can you help me?

Comment: `#Domaine/arts-du-langage` starting with `#` its a hash fragment and not a seperate path-fragments

Comment: yes. I've tried it with the _fragment parameter; but I'm not able to specify a variable part of the fragment; something like Document/{id}, to cover all the possible strings

Comment: The fragment is a client side construct (i.e. browser only), it isn't sent to the server at all, so you cannot rely on it on routes. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14462218) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/940905).

Comment: OK. So, it's an important issue with URIs build with #: it is impossible to dereference them precisely (see https://www.w3.org/2001/tag/doc/httpRange-14/2007-05-31/HttpRange-14)