# Bootstrap collapse if visiting mydomain.com/#collapseFour

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, anchor

I have a question

I user twitter bootstrap collapse on a page.
in the page there are **more collapses**:

**#collapseOne
#collapseTwo
#collapseThree**
...

there are normaly **all closed.**

but if I visit my link like this: **mydomain.com/#collapseFour** I want that one collapse **automatically** be shown.

thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it in PHP just add a class of 'in' to the accordion-body.

e.g

```
<div id="collapseFour" class="accordion-body collapse <?=($_GET['open'] == 4) ? "in" : ""?>">
```

then your url would be mydomain.com/?open=4

If you wanted to do it on the hash give this a read [Can I read the hash portion of the URL on my server-side application (PHP, Ruby, Python, etc.)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/940905/can-php-read-the-hash-portion-of-the-url)

And check out bootstrap documentation its pretty good!

Comment: Thank you. solved the issue like that, but
maybe there is a better solution.