# get the predefined variable in an encoded URL

Tags: php, ajax, url, get, encode

I am trying to get my predefined variable $_GET['loc']
Can anyone help me ? 
The problem is I don't want to disable my anchor tag for ajax using javascript. So what i did is I just added a hash-tag (#) on my href.
 The URL looks like this

```
http://localhost/test/onspecial/index.php#filter?loc=dn
```

What I need to attain is to access the $_GET['loc'].
I really appreciate any help.

my href attribute looks like this

```
<a href="#filter?loc=dn"></a>
```

here is my full navbar in index.php and wanted to get the value of $_GET['loc'] for my other queries :

```
<div class="navbar">
  <ul class="nav" id="nav">
    <li><a href="index.php">home</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.php">about us</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.php">contact us</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a id="drop_tog"href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" data-hover="dropdown" data-delay="1000" data-close-others="false">Location</a>
      <ul class="dopdown-menu" id="loc">
        <li id="loc1"><a tabindex="-1" href="#filter?loc=dc" >City</a></li>
        <li id="loc1"><a tabindex="-1" href="#filter?loc=ds" >South</a></li>
        <li id="loc1"><a tabindex="-1" href="#filter?loc=dn" >North</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>

  </ul>
</div>
```

javascript looks like this sending request on getresult.php :

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    function getLoc(param){
    //filter url
    var encode = param.substring(7);
     if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
     xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
     }
     else{
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
     }

     xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
      if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200){
      document.getElementById("li_start").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
      }
     }
     xmlhttp.open("GET","getresult.php"+encode,false);
     xmlhttp.send();
     }

    //handle anchor clicks
    $("ul#location li a").click(function(){
        var loc = $(this).attr("href");
        getLoc(loc);
    });


});
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/940905/can-php-read-the-hash-portion-of-the-url

Comment: What does an anchor tag have to do with ajax?

Comment: Access ` $_GET['loc']` in what way? Using what?

Answer (score 2):

Change :

```
http://localhost/test/onspecial/index.php#filter?loc=dn
```

To:

```
http://localhost/test/onspecial/index.php?loc=dn#filter
```

Basically, (almost) everything after a `?` in a URL is the "query string" until a `#` is reached. Then, (almost) everything after the `#` becomes an "anchor".

The `?` must come before the `#`.

**Edit** based on extra info and HTML.

I don't use jQuery, which it looks to me like you are using. Because of that, I re-wrote the javascript and a small part of your HTML in the following sample. In you HTML, you do not have a HTML tag with an id of `li_start`, but I assume that is somewhere else in your HTML.

The Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function linkClick(id) {
    page('li_start','/getresult.php?loc='+ id);
}
function loadPage(http, id, url){
    if((http.readyState == 4) && (http.status == 200 || window.location.href.indexOf("http") == -1)) {
        document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = http.responseText;
    }
}
function page(id, url){
    var http = false;
    var bustCacheParam = (url.indexOf("?")!=-1)? "&"+ new Date().getTime() : "?"+ new Date().getTime();
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        http = new XMLHttpRequest()
    } else if (window.ActiveXObject){
        try {
            http = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP")
        } catch (e) {
            try {
                http = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
            } catch (e) {}
        }
    } else {
        return false;
    }
    http.open('GET', url+bustCacheParam, true);
    http.onreadystatechange = function(){ loadPage(http, id, url); }
    http.send(null);
}
</script>
```

And the changed HTML:

```
<ul class="dopdown-menu" id="loc">
    <li id="loc1"><a tabindex="-1" href="#" onclick="linkClick('dc');return false">City</a></li>
    <li id="loc2"><a tabindex="-1" href="#" onclick="linkClick('ds');return false">South</a></li>
    <li id="loc3"><a tabindex="-1" href="#" onclick="linkClick('dn');return false">North</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: if i will change  the "#" with "?" that will make the full page to reload in my case what i need is for me to be able to get the value of $_GET['loc'] without deactivating the link with javascript.

Comment: Can I see a sample of the HTML? Maybe a simple mock-up of the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look of [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)

http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

```
<?php
$url = 'http://username:password@hostname/path?arg=value#anchor';
print_r(parse_url($url));
echo parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
?>

Array
(
    [scheme] => http
    [host] => hostname
    [user] => username
    [pass] => password
    [path] => /path
    [query] => arg=value
    [fragment] => anchor
)
```