# Getting URL in variable including internal link

Tags: php

I am getting my current page URL in variable using following code.

```
echo $url=$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
// Result: mywebsite/webpage.php
```

Everything goes well till here. But my webpage.php has some internal links. Which make URL like this

```
http://mywebsite/webpage.php#fragment-1
```

So when user is on this page and refresh page. I need to have fragment-1 in Result too but it shows same result as earlier. So how can I get '#fragment-1' value from url ?

Comment: and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/940905/can-php-read-the-hash-portion-of-the-url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. Hashes do not get sent to the web server.