# Bootstrap echo active for navbar <li> including dropdown children

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, navbar

This is for a basic bootstrap navbar with a dropdown, which is being used in a header.php (so each page cannot have it's own navbar with list-items with an active tag)

I've been using this to echo an active tag when you go to a page:

```
<?=echoActiveClassIfRequestMatches("balhblah")?>
```

First issue: When the `<li>` has a dropdown, the echo won't work.

Second issue: Figuring out a way to get that Home `<li>` to be active when a `<li>` from it's drop down is chosen, like "shakes".

```
    <li class="dropdown" <?=echoActiveClassIfRequestMatches("foods")?>>
        <a href="foods.php" >foods</a>

        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">shakes</a></li>

            <li><a href="#">cookies</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
```

Wanted to do a [Bootply](http://bootply.com/) for this, but when your href is # - basically I couldn't figure out how to link to another page in Bootply so you can see the result of the active echo. Not sure if you can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First issue: a html-tag (li in this case) can't have two class attributes, so you need to do something like `<li class="dropdown <?=echoActiveClassIfRequestMatches("foods")?>">` which results in `<li class="dropdown active">`. So you need the out put of your echoActiveClassIfRequestMatches-function too.

Second issue: php can't read the hash part of your url, see [Can I read the hash portion of the URL on my server-side application (PHP, Ruby, Python, etc.)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/940905/can-php-read-the-hash-portion-of-the-url). You will need javascript to to set the partent to active.

```
 $('.dropdown-menu li a').on('click', function() { $(this).parent().addClass('active');});
```

Comment: Thank you Bass! I'd vote for this answer, but I'm not up to that level yet. But thank you very much.