# Convert a named route to a hash (#) in CakePHP

Tags: html, cakephp, routes

In CakePHP, I want to convert this URL

```
example.com/FAQ/What-came-first-the-chicken-or-the-egg
```

to

```
example.com/FAQ#What-came-first-the-chicken-or-the-egg
```

using the `routes.php` and have the browser scroll to that anchor.

I tried this:

```
Router::connect('/FAQ/:faq',
    array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'faq', '#' => ':faq'),
    array('faq' => '[A-Za-z-_]+')
);
```

If I then do `debug($this->request->params)`, is says

```
array(
    'plugin' => null,
    'controller' => 'pages',
    'action' => 'FAQ',
    'named' => array(),
    'pass' => array(),
    'faq' => 'What-came-first-the-chicken-or-the-egg',
    '#' => ':faq'
)
```

and the browser doesn't scroll anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Not possible

A webserver has [no visibility whatsoever of the url fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/940905/can-php-read-the-hash-portion-of-the-url), as such routes based on the url fragment will never work.

### Your route needs to match the received url

If you request the url `/Foo/#hash` in a browser, the server will only receive `/Foo/` - this is the url that cake sees, this is the url that must match a route if you don't want to see errors. As such your route needs to be:

```
Router::connect('/FAQ',
    array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'faq')
);
```

Incidentally that's an odd route - the pages controller comes with a dynamic display function, it's not normal to create actions in this controller, rather use it like so:

```
Router::connect('/FAQ',
    array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display', 'faq')
);
```

Comment: Good point. However, according to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/940923/2483765), [`parse_url()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) CAN access the fragment (after the hashmark **#**) `PHP_URL_FRAGMENT`

Comment: Parse url can _parse_ a url with a url fragment. It can't however see the url fragment of the current request as it never leaves the browser, it is used exclusively for [client-side indirect referencing](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-3.5).

Answer (score -1):

I have not tested it:

```
Router::connect('/FAQ/#:faq',
    array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'faq'),
    array(
        'pass' => array('faq'),
        'faq' => '[A-Za-z-_]+'
    )
);
```

Comment: **Error:** _FAQController_ could not be found. when I do that.