# Get the string comes after # sign in URL by using CodeIgniter

Tags: javascript, codeigniter, url, query-string

How can I get the string comes after # sign the URL by using CodeIgniter?

example:

```
http://site.com/controller/function/#bla-bla
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't get the URL hash [via PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/940905/can-php-read-the-hash-portion-of-the-url) or CI.

This belongs to client-side, you should use JavaScript to achieve this:

```
var hash = window.location.hash;
console.log(hash); // "#bla-bla"
```

And you can remove the `#` character by `substr(1)`:

```
console.log(hash.substr(1)); // "bla-bla"
```

Comment: This is the correct answer, handle the hash on the frontend(browser level).  This is pretty pointless, but might work in your routes:    $route['controller/function/(\#\w.+)'] = 'controller/function/$1';

Comment: I think the browser doesn't send `GET` requests with `fragment` parts to the server.

Comment: You are correct. I'm baffled why the OP would want to send the hash tag. I think maybe he is trying to load content on a per div basis, in which case his going the wrong way about it