# Pass # as text in querystring in php

Tags: php, query-string, querystringparameter

I have this url https://www.industrialstores.com/search_results/Asco+8214G30+3%252F4%5C%5C%5C%220%252F5%23+Gas+Shutoff+Valve/46

but in above, `%23` is `#` before `Gas` in url and making all the things after this unreadable in php.

When I trying to fetch the value of `s` & `o` from the query string, I am not getting any value for `o` and for `s`, only `Asco+8214G30+3%252F4%5C%5C%5C%220%252F5` returns but it should return `Asco+8214G30+3%252F4%5C%5C%5C%220%252F5%23+Gas+Shutoff+Valve`

I am using httaccess rewrite to make this url 
    RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]{3,100})/([^/]+)/([^/]+)?$ index.php?page=$1&s=$2&o=$3 [L]

And code for fetching the querystring value as :

```
if(isset($_GET['s'])){

$search_keyword=str_replace("_"," ",$_GET['s']);
}
if(isset($_GET['o']) && $_GET['o'] !=''){
$searchin = $_GET['o'];
}
```

And setting query string values as below:

```
$keyword = urlencode(str_replace("/","%2F",$_REQUEST['search_keyword']));
```

Comment: Why do you have this URL in the first place, can you clarify what goes wrong where?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can PHP read the hash portion of the URL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/940905/can-php-read-the-hash-portion-of-the-url)

Comment: can you go here https://www.industrialstores.com/search_results/Asco+8214G30+3%252F4%5C%5C%5C%220%252F5%23+Gas+Shutoff+Valve/46

I am passing the value of s & o to ajax, you can check what parameters are passed to know the exact problem

Comment: urldecode is also returning this "Asco 8214G30 3/4\\\\\\\"0/5" not full text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I corrected this by converting `#` to `%23` before urlencoding the url using the code below,

```
str_replace("#","%23",$_REQUEST['search_keyword']);
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot retrieve nothing after the #, any browser will remove because this is a anchor.

This is explained at:
[Can I read the hash portion of the URL on my server-side application (PHP, Ruby, Python, etc.)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/940905/can-php-read-the-hash-portion-of-the-url)

You you want get this # you must slugify/urlize your url with some library like [Slugify](https://github.com/cocur/slugify) this will encode the "strange" chars.

Example:

```
use Cocur\Slugify\Slugify;

$slugify = new Slugify();//for iconv translit
echo $slugify->slugify('Hello World!'); // hello-world
```

I think that this is better than let to the browser make a simple url encode.

Answer (score 0):

try use rawurlencode() function.

Comment: yes. this function escape special chars. on destination code, use rawurldecode.

    echo rawurlencode('123#321'); // 123%23321 - %23 is # in hexadecimal

Comment: # is already coming as "%23" hexadecimal in the url https://www.industrialstores.com/search_results/Asco+8214G30+3%252F4%5C%5C%5C%220%252F5%23+Gas+Shutoff+Valve/46

but when I decode it, all the text after # is not returned

Comment: what the original text?

when i try:
[`code`]echo rawurldecode("Asco+8214G30+3%252F4%5C%5C%5C%220%252F5%23+Gas+Shutoff+Valve/46");
php return:
[`code`]Asco+8214G30+3%2F4\\\"0%2F5#+Gas+Shutoff+Valve/46

Comment: oriinal text is Asco 8214G30 3/4\"0/5# Gas Shutoff Valve

Comment: yo can go here https://www.industrialstores.com and put this text in search box and then click on search button, no record is found
On this page, I am passing this query string parameters to ajax, you can check in ajax call, params are wrong

Comment: when i use:
`rawurlencode("8214G30 3/4\"0/5# Gas Shutoff Valve")` 
return: `8214G30%203%2F4%220%2F5%23%20Gas%20Shutoff%20Valve` and rawurlDEcode works perfectly

Comment: ahhhhh, in ajax you need use `escape` in javascript request and rawurldecode in PHP

Comment: please can you go here industrialstores.com and put this text in search box and then click on search button, no record is found On this page, I am passing this query string parameters to ajax, you can check in ajax call, params are wrong

Comment: `escape (JS) = rawurlencode (PHP) ` `unescape (JS) = rawurldecode (PHP)`

Comment: you need send params in ajax escaped or your params sended broken

Comment: send in ajax url coded and in your requested page use rawurldecode

Comment: I tried but it is not working, when I am fetching the value of $_GET['s'], i am getting only string before the #
i am using this echo ">>>>>".$search_keyword=rawurldecode(str_replace("_"," ",$_GET['s']));

Comment: you can go here https://www.industrialstores.com/search_results/Asco%208214G30%203%252F4%5C%5C%5C%220%252F5%23%20Gas%20Shutoff%20Valve/46

you can see what we are getting from $_GET['s'], i echoed the value on page

Comment: I corrected this by converting 3 to %23 before urlencoding the url using this str_replace("#","%23",$_REQUEST['search_keyword']);