# Replace items in a url string in php

Tags: php

I am new to php.
And I am trying to replace the `"hash(#)"` in the url string with `"ampersand(&)".`

**For example:**

If the url is :`

```
http://www.abc.com/Cat/pgecategory.aspx?cid=8730&via=top#pge=2&pgeSize=36
```

I want to change it to

`http://www.abc.com/Cat/pgecategory.aspx?cid=8730&via=top&pge=2&pgeSize=36`

I have tried the following:

```
str_replace("#","&",$url);
```

But the above doesn't work? What am I doing wrong?

How can I achieve the above task?

Comment: What is the output of `var_dump($url)` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keep in mind that `str_replace` returns a string. It don't change the string you passed to it.

Try,

```
$url = str_replace("#", "&", $url); 
echo $url;
```

Answer (score 3):

The str_replace function returns the modified string, you have to set your url like this:

```
$url = str_replace("#","&",$url);
```

Answer (score 2):

How come it didn't work. ? Have you tried outputting your result ?

```
<?php
$url='http://www.abc.com/Cat/pgecategory.aspx?cid=8730&via=top#pge=2&pgeSize=36';
echo $url=str_replace("#","&",$url);
```

Comment: @Mr.Alien: `echo $var = 'stuff';` is [perfectly valid syntax](http://3v4l.org/L39e4).

Comment: @Mr.Alien, Check Jite's answer for your confusion.

Comment: @AmalMurali aaa I see, I thought it will throw an error because of echoing and assigning at the same time

Comment: @Mr.Alien: I too discovered this only recently (about 1 month back) :D

Comment: @AmalMurali there are so many things like these which are discovered by me reading questions on stack :D I thought that's not valid, so commented, anyways learnt something new again :P

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you are trying to do.

**If you are trying to modify the URL the client requested, this is not possible.**

Browsers simply do not send out the hash portion of the URL - so PHP can not even read it. However, you could read it through Javascript, with `window.location.hash`.

Source: [Can I read the hash portion of the URL on my server-side application (PHP, Ruby, Python, etc.)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/940905/can-php-read-the-hash-portion-of-the-url)

**If you are trying to modify the URL stored in a variable, this is possible.**

`str_replace` does not change the value of `$url` - it just returns the result. If you want `$url` to match the return value of `str_replace`:

```
$url = 'http://www.abc.com/Cat/pgecategory.aspx?cid=8730&via=top#pge=2&pgeSize=36';
$url = str_replace('#', '&', $url);
```

Or even shorter:

```
$url = str_replace('#', '&', 'http://www.abc.com/Cat/pgecategory.aspx?cid=8730&via=top#pge=2&pgeSize=36');
```