# Apache mod_rewrite to match URL with #

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I am trying to rewrite a bunch of pdf URLs. Most are already working, but I am having trouble  with a few of them. The problems all contain #page=xx in the URL. I want the #page=xx to be matched, and I do not want that string appended to the destination.

For example:

```
RewriteRule ^/pdfdir/test.pdf$  http://newlocation.com/dir1/newdir/abc.pdf [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^/pdfdir/test.pdf#page=3$  http://newlocation.com/dir1/newdir/def.pdf [R=301,L]
```

When I try to access my site with /pdfdir/test.pdf, it matches and rewrites correctly.  Now I want the request for page 3 inside test.pdf to go to a complete separate def.pdf in the new location. Right now, it is appending the #page=3 to the first match destination, which is abc.pdf.

Any suggestions would be most appreciated.

thanks

steve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The part after `#` is **fragment**

A fragment, by definition, is location *inside* a page.

`mod_rewrite` does not operate on fragment part.

In `RewriteRule` subject, you operate only on `URI`. Which means, the first rule is the only one applicable here, and hence it matches every time.

Comment: Thank you, that makes complete sense. Is there any way to accomplish what I am trying to do?

Comment: Do the URLs have to be like that? If you change the URL structure, you could either include page information in the uri, or put it in the query-string at least (and that would be match-able via `%{QUERY_STRING}` in `RewriteCond`...

Comment: Thanks, I do have to have the page number fragment, and I cant change the structure.  I think what I need to do is still have the 90 or so RewriteRules that don't contain the #page= string and have RewriteConds that will match those 15 or so strings above them in the rule set.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Then you're out of luck... This portion of url is not even sent to the server. See discussion on this regarding parsing this in php: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/940905/can-php-read-the-hash-portion-of-the-url