# Redirect to current url including hash '#' upon form submission

Tags: jquery

I am trying to basically refresh the page upon form submission, but INCLUDING a hash '#'.

For example, the url is:  www.example.com/segment#foo

Using:

```
$("#form-name").submit(function(){
 location.reload();
});
```

does not include the hash.

Any help many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just adding the fragment (#foo) in the url in the action attr of the form ?

```
<form method="POST" action="http://example.com/segment#foo" ...>
```

Answer (score 0):

The fragment won't be sent to the server ([Can I read the hash portion of the URL on my server-side application (PHP, Ruby, Python, etc.)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/940905/can-php-read-the-hash-portion-of-the-url)) so you will have to encode that data some other way.