# how i Passing Value from document.URL to php

Tags: javascript, php

I am using the following piece of Javascript code to get the link from the browser:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.write(document.URL);
</script>
```

How can I pass the value to PHP or get the link to use it on PHP code?

Please, that's just what I want to know, I do not want other answers about how I can get the link directly through php. I know already that there are ways to get the link through PHP directly by useing `$_GET`, `$_SERVER` but they do not get the link with the hash and I want get the value after the hash.

I.e.: `http://sitename.com/t10.html#post22`

Comment: The hash is irrelevant to the HTTP Request and is actually only relevant to the browser. So you simply cannot get it using PHP.

Comment: thnx , that is not what i asked about , i ask about how i pass the value from java to php , what you say i already know it .

Comment: do you want a pure javascript method or are you ok with using a library like jquery?

Comment: You can't pass values from javascript to PHP

Comment: @anurupr i think pure javascript is enough , Because i want from it get only the full link from browser , and i will use the value on PHP . THNX

Comment: @Chosen Wann , OH really ? i don't know that .. so how i can get all link from broswer with hash , sure there is a way to do that

Comment: @o6qr as far as I know, there isn't.

Comment: AJAX or just post it via a form. @ChosenWann, there is a way.

Comment: @putvande I might have found something. check my answer in a few minutes.

Comment: @putvande , okay how i get full link by ajax , i don't know much about it

Comment: @Chosen Wann , okay brother waiting you .. but u have to know i check this link already http://stackoverflow.com/questions/940905/can-php-read-the-hash-portion-of-the-url

Comment: @o6qr also, do you mind me asking what are you planning to do with whatever is after the hash after you get it? how will you process it?

Comment: @Chosen Wann , okay i want to get the number of post from broswer to know if user login or see this post or not , there is a field at the database i will insert on it value 1 or 0 , 1 means user see the post , 0 means user don't see the post

Comment: @o6qr then why not simply set it as a parameter rather than a hashtag? `example.com/index.php?post_id=1`

Comment: @Chosen Wann , yeah that's will be very easy to use $_GET but  the links like this #post99 already with hash , i cannot change it to post=99

Answer (score 0):

Use ajax (jquery or any similar library) to post the data to your php script.

Comment: thnx , all answer about use ajax , but i don't know about it , how i use ajax to get full link or get what is after hash ??

Comment: @sh0ber the answer does point the questioner to the right direction.

Comment: @Howard Pointers are nice.  Answers are better.

Answer (score 0):

For a solution, we'll be using a cookie to store the url in javascript then retrieve it in PHP

so here's the javascript part

```
<script>
    document.cookie = 'url='+document.url;
</script>
```

Then in PHP, simply

```
<?php
    echo $_COOKIE['url'];
?>
```

Comment: okay i try it and print the var, this what that appears (undefined)

Answer (score 0):

```
var myHash = window.location.hash.substr(1);
```

You can the pass it to a php page using [post()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

```
$.post("mypage.php", {hash: myHash}, function (data) {
    alert(data);
});
```

Comment: thnx brother , i don't understand the code so good , and i'm want pass  the value var from java to php on same page , not pass to another page .

Answer (score 0):

thnx brothers .. i found The solution to my problem After hundreds of attempts
,the closest solution to my problem  by @Chosen Wann

first this code of java to get waht's after hash from the link

```
<script>
document.cookie = 'url='+window.location.hash;
</script>
```

and you can passing the value to PHP BY

```
$_COOKIE['url'];
```

if your links like

```
http://sitename.com/t10.html#post22
```

you can get the number of post

```
<?php
$inurl = explode("#post",$_COOKIE['url']);  
echo $inurl[1];
?>
// Value Output:  22
```